# Getting a permission error while trying to resize images in a file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, permissions, python-os

I am making a program in Tensorflow to guess the type of flower it is. I was told that to make the program more accurate, I should resize all the images to the same size. I was getting a permission error, but even after changing all the permissions to give admin, and even running in admin Command Prompt, it still didn't work. It also gave me a success message after I used the "icacls" command to alter the permissions.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

target_size = (224, 224)

for class_name in os.listdir('C:/Users/myname/OneDrive/Desktop/pyimportant/Automation/Flower Classification V2/V2/ Training Data'):
    class_dir = os.path.join('C:/Users/myname/OneDrive/Desktop/pyimportant/Automation/Flower Classification V2/V2/Training Data', class_name)
    for filename in os.listdir(class_dir):
        image_path = os.path.join(class_dir, filename)
        with Image.open(image_path) as img:
            img = img.resize(target_size)
            img.save(image_path)
```

If you have any questions about specs or such, I'd be happy to answer!

Also, in case you want, here's the dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/utkarshsaxenadn/flower-classification-5-classes-roselilyetc

Comment: Running IDE as administrator should work. Are u sure that you’re running everything with admin privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to restart my computer, and then it was working fine. Sorry for the inconvinience! I don't know why this would happen, but sometimes restarting just helps.

Comment: Better to put this advice kind of answer not as response but as a comment